# Crash when clicking an overlay item in mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    badplatsName = getIntent().getStringExtra("se.brickit.badplatsen.badplatsname");
    lat = getIntent().getIntExtra("se.brickit.badplatsen.lat",0);
    lon = getIntent().getIntExtra("se.brickit.badplatsen.lon",0);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley_flask);
    BrMapViewItemOverlay itemizedoverlay = new BrMapViewItemOverlay(drawable);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat,lon);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, badplatsName, "");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
    mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(6, 6);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
}
```

When i click on the overlay item the application crashes. anybody know the reason why?

the logcat is a bit odd too as it appears to be trying to launch an activity but all i want it to do is show a box with the name when clicked.

```
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:743)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:273)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at se.brickit.badplatsen.BrMapViewItemOverlay.onTap(BrMapViewItemOverlay.java:43)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:347)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:647)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3765)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:905)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1701)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2093)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1685)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1802)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-20 14:36:56.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15856):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 14:36:58.163: ERROR/ActivityManager(96): fail to set top app changed!
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.brickit.badplatsen/se.brickit.badplatsen.Tabs}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at se.brickit.badplatsen.Tabs.onCreate(Tabs.java:192)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
07-20 14:36:58.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15896):     ... 11 more
07-20 14:37:00.053: ERROR/ClockWidget(209): weatherClock onReceive~ mUseAnimation:false
07-20 14:37:00.053: ERROR/ClockWidget(209): weatherClock onReceive~ mUseAnimation:false
```

Ps here is the overlay class:

```
public class BrMapViewItemOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;

public BrMapViewItemOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}

public BrMapViewItemOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(defaultMarker);
    mContext = context;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you do in onTap or in MapView onTouchListener method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

`BrMapViewItemOverlay itemizedoverlay = new BrMapViewItemOverlay(drawable);`

with

```
 BrMapViewItemOverlay itemizedoverlay = new BrMapViewItemOverlay(drawable, this);
```

You have not passed the context and hence inflating AlertDialog is causing failure.

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat output, i can say there is a problem at line number **192** in your **Tabs.java** file, in the same line, i am sure you are trying to refer any resources like strings, colors, drawables or any but it is giving ResourceNotFoundException just because of it is not getting the ID of that resource actually.

Just for try, do the **`project -> clean`** so that it builds the project again. Its just my guess as i had also did many times.

In short, just check the line number 192 in Tabs.java file.